# Is $f : (-1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ differentiable at $x = 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> Is $f : (-1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$ differentiable at $a = 0$?

By the definition of the derivative I get the following $$f'(a) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(a+t) - f(a)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{a+t}-\frac{1}{a}}{t}= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{-1}{a^2 + at} = -\frac{1}{a^2}$$

so $f$ is differentiable at $a$. However if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ then $f$ must be continuous at $a = 0$ a contradiction since $f$ is not continuous at $a = 0$.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: How can a function be differentiable at a point which is not in its domain?

Comment: `By the definition of the derivative ...` What is $f(a)$ on the next line when $a=0\,$?

Comment: You can't define a function $(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by  $f(x) = 1/x$.  A professor of mine once said that asking about differentiability of a function at a point outside its domain makes about as much sense as asking about its differentiability at the San Diego Zoo :)

Comment: You do realize that $\frac{1}{a^2}$ itself does not exist when a= 0, don't you?

Comment: "You can't define a function (−1,1)→R by f(x)=1/x
. A professor of mine once said that asking about differentiability of a function at a point outside its domain makes about as much sense as asking about its differentiability at the San Diego Zoo :) "  The pandas are differentiable but the lemurs aren't.

Comment: "$f'(a) = -\frac 1{a^2}$ so f is differentiable at a".  Since when has $- \frac 1{0^2}$ been a defined value?

Answer (score 5):

Look at what you were doing here: $$f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h}$$

When you wrote that, you need to remember that the $f$ you're talking about is $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, and that the $a$ you're talking about is $0$. Replacing those things, this is what you wrote: $$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{0 + h} - \frac{1}{0}}{h}$$

A limit, essentially, is a question: what happens to this number when I make $h$ small? In this case, "this number" doesn't exist - to find it, you'd need to divide by zero! So what happens to it is that it stays not existing, and $f'(0)$ therefore doesn't exist. And what does "not differentiable at $0$" mean if not "$f'(0)$ does not exist"?

Alternatively, you can see the issue from your conclusion, too. Remember, just because you can write something down doesn't mean it exists - I can write "$x + 1 = 2$ and $x + 2 = 4$", but that doesn't mean there is such a number. In this case, you found that $f'(a) = -\frac{1}{a^2}$ for any $a$; but only for $a \neq 0$ does this thing you've written exist.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f'(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2}$ is not defined at $x=0$ (uniquely there) then it isn't continuous and $f(x)$ isn't differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Whether $-\frac{1}{x^2}$ isn't continuous at $x = 0$ doesn't matter. It's only that it isn't defined there.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126: ok, but still is true and maybe it serves to stress the viewpoint